# how can i change the pin's color in mkmapview in swift?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit

Here is the code that i use for setting up the map, it's works perfectly,but it shows the ping in red. My problem is how can i can change the color, for example to show the pin in green... (Swift)

```
var theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
var vehiculeLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((self.longitud as NSString).doubleValue, (self.latitud as NSString).doubleValue)
            var theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(vehiculeLocation, theSpan)
            self.map.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)

            var point = MKPointAnnotation()
            point.coordinate = vehiculeLocation              
            point.title = "Direccion : "+self.adressmap;
point.subtitle = "Velocidad : "+self.speedmap+" KPH / "+"En ubicacion" ;
                self.map.addAnnotation(point)
```

I was trying to use this code

```
 self.map.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
```

but it does not work

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

You want to override the `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:'

In that method, create an `MKPinAnnotationView`, set it's color, and return it.

This is not specific to swift. I added the `MKMapView`and 'MapKit' keys to your question, since it IS specific to mapkit.

Comment: i 'm trying to do it, but i have this errorr :     
i have this error " use of unresolved identifier annotationView.image " how can i resolve it please? –

Comment: How am I supposed to tell without seeing the code?!? Edit your original question with an "EDIT:" mark at the bottom and post your new code along with the error(s) you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Set the icon of the pin if you don't like the choice of colors with:

`annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "chartreusepin")`

Comment: i have this error " use of unresolved identifier annotationView.image " how can i resolve it please?

Comment: Context is important, so we need the lines above the code above. How is annotationView declared and do you have an image in your project with the name used in UIImage(named: "<image name>" ?